# VBox Guest Additions installation can't find headers for Kali kernal 4.14.0-kali1-amd64

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, header-file

I have installed Kali in VirtualBox and now trying to install Guest Additions to get full screen view.

I updated and installed my packages and installed dkms.  When I try to install linux-headers I get the following:

```
# apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-amd64 is already the newest version (4.14.2-1kali1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 86 not upgraded.
```

The headers installed are as follows:

```
# dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-headers
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-amd64        install
linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-common       install
linux-headers-amd64             install
```

When I try to run the Guest Additions CD I get the following:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.0.40 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.0.40 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-kali1-amd64
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.14.0-kali1-amd64
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following
module compilation fails then this could be the reason.

Building the main Guest Additions module ...fail!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
Press Return to close this window...
```

It appears to me that the correct linux headers for the kernal are installed. Why is VBox not able to find them?

Tried updating to VBox 5.2.2 but after removing existing version and installing 5.2.2 I was unable to launch Kali-Linux - screenshot attached [image].

Comment: Upgrade virtualbox to `VirtualBox 5.2.2` version (for windows or linux) https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads theen install the guest addition.

Comment: Make sure the guest additions are the right one for your Vbox

Comment: VBox is VirtualBox Graphical User Interface Version 5.0.40_Ubuntu r115130

VBox additions is VBOXADDITIONS_5.0.40_115130

Comment: After upgrading to 5.2.2 kali fails to launch.  VBox reports "The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing"  Running "/sbin/vboxconfig" did not help

Comment: `The headers for the current running kernel were not found`: reboot first to have a new kernel (which had better be installed) matching the headers.

Answer (score 0):

You sould follow the tutorial to install VirtualBox Gest Additions on the [Kali Linux Official Documentation](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest).

> The VirtualBox Guest Additions provide proper mouse and screen
>   integration, as well as folder sharing, with your host operating
>   system. To install them, proceed as follows.
>
> Start up your Kali Linux virtual machine, open a terminal window and
>   issue the following commands.
>
> ```
> apt-get update
> apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11
> reboot
> ```

Comment: Using the method in the official doc I get the exact same error....The installation fails during the installation of the main Guest Additions module, right after the script reports not being able to find the headers (however, this was also reported in the official documentation).

Answer (score 0):

if you believe u installed headers right then follow those steps

```
Cd /media/cdrom
sudo chmod +x VBoxLinuxAdditions.run // chmod: changing permissions of 'VBoxLinuxAdditions.run': Read-only file system. ignoere this message

sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

after installation u have to reboot your system